# Cython extension not re-installing via setup.py after modification

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

So, I have a Python package, with a Cython extension.

File structure:

```
-lib_name (dir)
    -setup.py
    -lib_name (dir)
        -__init__.py
        -python_thing.py
        -cython_thing.pyx
```

Here's my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extension = Extension(
    name="cython_thing",
    sources=["lib_name/cython_thing.pyx"],
    extra_compile_args=["-ffast-math"]
)

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extension, language_level=3),
    name='lib_name',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['lib_name'],
    install_requires=['numpy', 'sklearn']
)
```

And here's my `__init__.py`:

```
from . import *

__all__ = ['python_thing', 'cython_thing']
```

I ran `sudo python3 setup.py install` one time, and everything seemed to go without a hitch. I saw the pyx file get cythonized and compiled, the package installed, and then I could seemingly use the whole package with no problem.

*However*, I've now made a modification to the `.pyx` file for some troubleshooting. When I re-install the package with `install` or `develop`, and attempt to use it, it continues to use the old version of the code. To confirm this, I've gone as far as adding `print('THIS IS THE NEW CODE')` to functions in the `.pyx` file to make sure it's identifying itself. However, these lines never print, telling me that I'm definitely still running the old code somehow. I *do* see Cython re-cythonizing the new code, but it must not be installing it, because it never runs.

I've already tried `sudo pip3 uninstall lib_name`, then re-installing, but no dice. Still get old code path.

In case it helps, I'm importing stuff from the `.pyx` file by using `from lib_name.cython_thing import cython_function`.

I'm fairly certain this must be a problem with my package structure or maybe some built object getting cached somewhere. Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong? How do I ensure my package gets fully re-installed when needed?

Comment: Did you try removing the old built extensions?

Comment: Your `sudo python3 setup.py install` will install in a system directory (/usr/lib/... or /usr/local/...). Can you `python3 -c 'import lib_name ; print(lib_name.__file__)` to confirm where it finds the lib_name it uses?

Comment: `rm -rf build/` when in the directory containing the `setup.py` script, then `python setup.py build_ext`. You may also try a `python setup.py clean build_ext` for a one-liner, but I'm not sure whether it will erase the build dir completely.

Answer (score 1):

When developing, I usually have a virtual environment in which I install my cython package in developer mode via (in the folder with `setup.py`):

```
 pip install -e .
```

rerunning `pip install -e .` will update to the current state.

When using `pip install` (or `setup.py install`) one needs to uninstall the package, before it can be reinstalled.

---

The above is fast and thus convenient, however one has also to check installation in a clean virtual environment from time to time.

Comment: Thanks. I think there may have been overlapping issues. First, I needed to have `name="lib_name.cython_thing",` in the Extension definition to export it properly. Second, as you mentioned, I needed to be uninstalling the package and reinstalling... For some reason, without Cython, I always had no problem using `setup.py develop`.